# Fatal error when using gzopen() : undefined function

Tags: php, zlib

I want to open a `.gz` file using the gzopen function and i got this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function gzopen()
```

Here some details about my installation:

```
OS : Ubuntu 10.04 up to date
Apache version : 2.2.14 
PHP : 5.2.10-2ubuntu6
```

in the `Zlib` section for `phpinfo()`, i've got this:

```
ZLib Support                   enabled
Stream Wrapper support         compress.zlib://
Stream Filter support          zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
Compiled Version               1.2.3.3
Linked Version                 1.2.3.3
zlib.output_compression        Off
zlib.output_compression_level  -1
zlib.output_handler            no value
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: What does `extension_loaded('zlib')` return?

Comment: Maybe you've different PHP Versions or php.ini files for webserver and bash ? Check php -i | grep ZLIB

Answer (score 3):

Seems like a problem with this specific build of PHP for Ubuntu. See [here for more details](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/432291)

They mention un-commenting a line within the distribution which then fixes the problem.

I imagine this will be the cause, hopefully following implementing the change above will fix the problem. Alternatively you could install a newer version of PHP if you are able to.

Comment: Finally I've upgraded PHP to the version 5.3.2 and it works well